# Handle unknown soap message from WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have a client generated using SVCUTIL from WSDL + XSD in C# .net console app. All fine but for some logical error handling purpose, client may receive a response message, which is not defined in WSDL hence deserialization & will fail but method does not throw exception but returns null.

Is there any generic way to handle this situation or I define a fault/error message xsd(for soap message returned by server) and in case of null response, handle/deserialize the message.

PS: My remote service can not throw a fault exception for logical errors.(yeah a bit of blockage there).

Comment: If your service is returning a message that is not in the WSDL, then it is broken. How is that not "broken"?

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your reply. It's not broken, I call the the method and I get null response,  no exception, I use fiddler and see what was returned it was another message, can't be deserialized by message contract. We have to return another message from service because we can not throw a soap fault because of logical error(limitation).

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Everything that can be returned from the service _must_ be defined in the WSDL.

Comment: hmmm good point, As you know I am newbie here, I'll try to regenerate WSDL may be then I see some error messages but what if I simply put a wrong message in response from method. Acutely my WCF service is defined in a different internal tool, so I have difficulties explaining that part. First I try regenerate WSDL, I'll get back. Thank you again for reply John.I appreciated it.

Answer (score 2):

WSDL is contract. It is same like if you have two objects and defined interface between them. If the first object calls the operation on the second object it expects return value defined by interface. If we would use some non-strongly typed language the second object would be able to return different type of return value and the first object would fail because of unexpected error.

Programming languages have approach to solve this - in case of .NET you would use `object` type as return value and you would always have to manually investigate what type did you receive and how to handle the return value. In case of WCF we also have such high level type - `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` but you really don't want to use it because in such case you will have to build SOAP request manually and parse incoming responses manually.

As a side note in web services single request type has always single response type and zero or more error types (which are SOAP faults). If you have a service which returns different response types on single request type such service is not "valid" web service and cannot be described by WSDL. Because of that it also cannot be in strongly typed way provided by auto-generated WCF proxy.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have a situation which is not standard in terms of WCF. I try explain again. My WSDL method has only input and output parameter(complex type).This method are created using a tool, which does not expose any thing like throwing an exception manually on logical errors or custom errors. So we have got an option to cast another message as output response. Okay we receive that in and generated client can not deserialize the response as it does not know how to do that. So I wanted to know is there any standard way to handle this deserialization failure.I hope I am clear.Thanks.

Comment: No it is not. In such case you must work with SOAP message directly. Writing different outputs is not valid in web services. If you need multiple output types you should model your first output to support theme. For example adding field for result code or using XSD choice internally.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I'll add a result type field in Message XSD and check that in response for custom errors. Thanks again.